# Is OSGi Component with metatype and without properties illegal state in SCR?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

Assume that [SCR Annotations](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html) is used in an example. Consider class:

```
@Component(metatype = true, label = "This is my ACME class implementation)
public class AcmeImpl implements Acme {}
```

The metatype descriptor is close to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><metatype:MetaData xmlns:metatype="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/metatype/v1.0.0" localization="OSGI-INF/metatype/com.my.AcmeImpl">
    <OCD id="com.my.Acme" name="%com.my.Acme.name" description="%com.my.AcmeImpl.description"/>
    <Designate pid="com.my.AcmeImpl">
        <Object ocdref="com.my.Acme"/>
    </Designate>
</metatype:MetaData>
```

The issue is, regarding to `MetaData` [scheme](https://osgi.org/xmlns/metatype/v1.0.0/metatype.xsd):

```
<complexType name="OCD">
    <sequence>
        <element name="AD" type="metatype:AD" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <element name="Icon" type="metatype:Icon" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </sequence>
    <!-- not important part -->
</complextType>
```

Therefore, lack of `AD` node in `OCD` makes this metatype unusable and not appearing in OSGi Felix web console. Worth to mention that adding any non-private `Property` annotation results in adding one `AD` node thus making scheme validated properly and configuration can be created on Felix web console side.

The state of not having any property is not explicitly forbidden anywhere else and should throw error during [Apache SCR Maven plugin](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html) processing. Is there any reason behind that? How to make this `Component` still configurable without adding any `Property` to it?